# Gradient and maximum and minimum changes

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose we have a function of $x,y,z$ such as :

$$f(x,y,z) = x^2e^y + 3\sin z$$

If we calculate the gradient of this then that would provide us with a vector quantity which represents the most rapid change.

However if i want to find the direction corresponding to a **minimum** change in $|f|$ then how would i go about it?